# PHP Clone td with text

Tags: php, dom

I have a code

```
$elem->parentNode->parentNode->appendChild($elem->parentNode->cloneNode(true));
```

It takes a long time.
But if remove `true` it works

`$elem` - text in `<td>`

Comment: define "long time". If it's just a simple `<td>` why do you need the `deep` param set to `true`?

Comment: because I want create copy td with text

Answer (score 1):

```
  $clone = $elem->parentNode->cloneNode(true);
  $elem->parentNode->setAttribute('data-clone','0');
  for($i=1; $i<count($this->vars[$elem->nodeValue]); $i++) {
    $clone = $elem->parentNode->cloneNode(true);
    $clone->setAttribute('data-clone',$i);
    $elem->parentNode->parentNode->appendChild($clone);
  }
```